# execute a SQL Server Job using SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to execute a SQL Server 2008 job using an execute SQL task in SSIS Package.

I used EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'MORNING - iflagship_DataLoad_FULL';

This works on starting the job but it returns success when the job starts . I want the EXECUTE SQL TASK to stay Yellow (Executing) until the job is finished and than turn Green (Success ) before it goes to the next step.

Any ideas how this can be possible ?

The below code executes the job but returns success right away even when the job is still running.

```
     alter procedure [dbo].[StartAgentJobAndWait](@job nvarchar(128),       @maxwaitmins int = 0) --, @result int output)
     as begin

     set NOCOUNT ON;
    set XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

declare @running as int
declare @seccount as int
declare @maxseccount as int
declare @start_job as bigint
declare @run_status as int

set @start_job = cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) as bigint) * 1000000 + datepart(hour, getdate()) * 10000 + datepart(minute, getdate()) * 100 + datepart(second, getdate())

set @maxseccount = 60*@maxwaitmins
set @seccount = 0
set @running = 0



declare @job_owner sysname
declare @job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

set @job_owner = SUSER_SNAME()

-- get job id
select @job_id=job_id
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
where sj.name='Check for Dealers Sent not Boarded on CSC'

-- invalid job name then exit with an error
if @job_id is null
    RAISERROR (N'Unknown job: %s.', 16, 1, 'Check for Dealers Sent not Boarded on CSC')

-- output from stored procedure xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs is captured in the following table
declare @xp_results TABLE ( job_id                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
                            last_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
                            last_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
                            next_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
                            next_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
                            next_run_schedule_id  INT              NOT NULL,
                            requested_to_run      INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL
                            request_source        INT              NOT NULL,
                            request_source_id     sysname          COLLATE database_default NULL,
                            running               INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL
                            current_step          INT              NOT NULL,
                            current_retry_attempt INT              NOT NULL,
                            job_state             INT              NOT NULL)

-- start the job
declare @r as int
exec @r = msdb..sp_start_job 'Check for Dealers Sent not Boarded on CSC'

-- quit if unable to start
if @r<>0
    RAISERROR (N'Could not start job: %s.', 16, 2, 'Check for Dealers Sent not Boarded on CSC')

-- start with an initial delay to allow the job to appear in the job list (maybe I am missing something ?)
WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:01';
set @seccount = 1

-- check job run state
insert into @xp_results
execute master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

set @running= (SELECT top 1 running from @xp_results)

while @running<>0 and @seccount < @maxseccount
begin
    WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:01';
    set @seccount = @seccount + 1

    delete from @xp_results

    insert into @xp_results
    execute master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

    set @running= (SELECT top 1 running from @xp_results)
end

-- result: not ok (=1) if still running

if @running <> 0 begin
    -- still running
    return 0
end
else begin

    -- did it finish ok ?
    set @run_status = 0

    select @run_status=run_status
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    where job_id=@job_id
      and cast(run_date as bigint) * 1000000 + run_time >= @start_job

    if @run_status=1
        return 1  --finished ok
    else  --error
        RAISERROR (N'job %s did not finish successfully.', 16, 2, 'Check for Dealers Sent not Boarded on CSC')

end

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

DECLARE
    @ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ErrorNumber     INT,
    @ErrorSeverity   INT,
    @ErrorState      INT,
    @ErrorLine       INT,
    @ErrorProcedure  NVARCHAR(200);

SELECT
    @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
    @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
    @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

SELECT @ErrorMessage =
    N'Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d, ' +
        'Message: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();

RAISERROR
    (
    @ErrorMessage,
    @ErrorSeverity,
    1,
    @ErrorNumber,    -- original error number.
    @ErrorSeverity,  -- original error severity.
    @ErrorState,     -- original error state.
    @ErrorProcedure, -- original error procedure name.
    @ErrorLine       -- original error line number.
    );

END CATCH

     end
```

Comment: I see that in the sample code the jobname is hardcoded. Try to get a fresh one from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648475/need-to-start-agent-job-and-wait-until-completes-and-get-success-or-failure

Answer (score 0):

Are the 2 SSIS tasks linked to each other?
It would be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of the SSIS package

Comment: The SSIS package just includes one Control Flow that Is "EXECUTE SQL TASK" which just executes the stored procedure below.